# Cost difference of different Vias

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I would like to know what could be typical cost difference of :

1. Through hole via (say x $)
2. Blind Via
3. Buried Via in a high dense PCB.

Which is costlier & Why?

Comment: Don't ask us, ask your PCB shop!  Prices vary.

Answer (score 6):

It isn't a per-via cost. A normal PCB has all of its layers etched, laminated together, drilled and then plated. If you have blind or buried vias, regardless of how many there are, then multiple passes of the last three steps are required, and this is where the extra cost comes from. In other words, the cost of the whole board goes up as soon as you make the decision to use blind and/or buried vias.

Answer (score 4):

The best way of knowing the price sensitivity for special features is to go to a fab website that does online quote, like [Sunstone](http://www.sunstone.com) or [4PCB](http://www.4pcb.com/)

As a rule of thumb, consider that each special feature almost doubles the price for both the unit cost and the setup. As DaveTweed said, that's independent of how much you use such feature in your board.